# Working with current values of properties of the ViewModel with Knockout-Kendo.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I recently found this great component -> [Knockout-Kendo.js](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/index.html).

I use it to handle some behaviors with [kendoComboBox](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/ComboBox.html).

The synchronization with the viewmodel works perfectly.

I want to listen changes of the control to execute some actions based on the current selected value.

I don't see any property that I can bind in the 'data-bind' attribute to listen changes but I know that internally, the knockout-kendo component listen changes and this is how the viewmodel is able to by sync with the control.

If I try to listen the valueChange event of the control, the problem is my eventhandler is catched before the viewmodel and while running in my eventhandler, I just have the previous value of the control using the viewmodel.

Look at this binding configuration in the component. What I understand is I'm able to use 'enabled', 'search', 'data', 'value' and any other exposed properties of the telerik control. What would be nice would be to define in data-bind attribute a property 'change' with an eventhandler linked in my viewmodel and be sure my eventhandler would be called after the internal eventhandler of the knockout-kendo component.

```
createBinding({
    name: "kendoAutoComplete",
    events: {
        change: VALUE,
        open: {
            writeTo: ISOPEN,
            value: true
        },
        close: {
            writeTo: ISOPEN,
            value: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        enabled: ENABLE,
        search: [SEARCH, CLOSE],
        data: function(value) {
            ko.kendo.setDataSource(this, value);
        },
        value: VALUE
    }
```

});

I know I can try to modify the order of bind of events to be sure my eventhandler must be called after the synchronization of the viewmodel but I think it's a very bad practice.

Anybody have an idea how I can solve this problem with elegance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned *why* you want to do this. I can imagine two reasons:

- To trigger some UI behavior/logic *directly*;
- To trigger business logic (which may in turn trigger UI changes of course);

For people landing at this question with the latter case, here's an alternative solution. (This answer may not be a straight up answer to the OP's question, but seems useful enough to post it here.)

---

Suppose you have this basic view model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.kendoObservable = ko.observable("Some text")
};
```

There are two ways you can *indirectly* respond to changes by Kendo. First, for simple cases, there's [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
    // Option 1, add this to ViewModel
    self.dependentObservable = ko.computed(function() {
         return self.kendoObservable() === "" ? "Empty" : "Not empty"; // example
    });
```

This `dependentObservable` will be modified each time the `kendoObservable` changes. Basic stuff.

If you want to do something more complex when `kendoObservable` changes, e.g. do an AJAX call or whatnot, you may need a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables):

```
    // Option 2, add this to ViewModel
    self.kendoObservable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
         // Possibly do an AJAX call here or whatnot. Example:
         alert("The new value is: " + newValue);
    });
```

This will allow you to fire some complex logic each time the `kendoObservable` changes. AFAIK you need to check yourself whether the `newValue` is actually a *changed* value, at least in some versions of KO.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much Jeroen. With 'subscribe', I can do exactly what I want. The answer was just in my face while reading in the documentation section of Knockout website.